# Run docker cp excluding files from .dockerignore

Tags: docker

Is there a way to use `docker cp` so that it exclude files/folders from `.dockerignore` the way COPY in dockerfile does?

Comment: Sorry, judging from the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/), it seems that this is not supported. You could consider raising a feature request via [GitHub](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues).

Comment: For what reason you need to copy with docker cp ? Maybe your process can be improved

Comment: I want to update files inside the docker container but I don't want to use `volumes` because I do not want to locally see changes to files done inside the container.

Comment: @6be709c0 my use case in arriving at this question is that I am troubleshooting a docker build process by reproducing that process in an interactive container

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way ([docker cp](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/)). A hacky workaround is to execute a script, that makes symbolic links of the files you need. After that you copy these files. But thats not how docker should be used.

If you want change the code inside your container, then you have to build a new image.
If want you to change configurations then use other mechanism like volumes or environments-variables.
And if you want to pull out some generated files, then use volumes instead.

Side node: I dont know what you like to do, but keep in mind that docker is not a virtual machine. See https://devopscon.io/blog/docker/docker-vs-virtual-machine-where-are-the-differences/